# What are the special values of WPF's Binding engine when converting values?

Tags: .net, wpf, ivalueconverter, imultivalueconverter

I already know about the [Binding.DoNothing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.binding.donothing.aspx) that one can return from an IValueConverter implementation to signify that no other operation should take place.

However, I cannot find a reference, or documentation nicely summing out, what the other special values are - such as returning the fallback value. What are they?

Comment: Fallback happens if the binding does not work in the first place or possibly if some exception is thrown when binding.

Comment: the best way to know about such values is to read articles about [Binding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms617928.aspx) and [BindingBase](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms618281.aspx) classes. Everything you can use is listed there

Answer (score 16, accepted):

[`Binding.DoNothing`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.binding.donothing.aspx) is an object instance that *you actively return from a value converter*; it instructs the binding engine to not update the value of the target property at all. Here's [a nice example](http://joshsmithonwpf.wordpress.com/2007/08/20/prevent-a-binding-from-updating-too-frequently/) by Josh Smith of what you might use this for.

[`FallbackValue`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.bindingbase.fallbackvalue.aspx) is a property that you set on bindings; it allows you to specify the value to be applied to the target property if:

- the binding source cannot be resolved (e.g. wrong binding path), or
- the binding property value is equal to [`DependencyProperty.UnsetValue`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.dependencyproperty.unsetvalue.aspx), or
- a value converter used for the binding throws an exception, or
- a value converter used for the binding returns `DependencyProperty.UnsetValue`, or
- the value produced by the binding pipeline is not valid for the target property (e.g. wrong type)

[`TargetNullValue`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.bindingbase.targetnullvalue.aspx) is also a property you set on bindings; it allows you to specify the value to be applied to the target property if the value of the source property is `null`. For example, if you bind a text box to a string property `TargetNullValue` lets you pick what appears in the text box if the source string is `null`.

Comment: Ah! DependencyProperty.UnsetValue. That was the one I was looking for.